# What is the status of the equidistribution root numbers of elliptic curves' L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

In Section 7 of Alice Silverberg's [Rank "Cheat Sheet"](http://math.uci.edu/~asilverb/connectionstalk.pdf), Silverberg stated

> The Bhargava Conjecture: For each $n >
> > 1$ the average size of
>   $S_{n}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is
>   $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{d|n} d$.

Here $S_{n}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is the $n$-Selmer group of $E/\mathbb{Q}$. Silverberg remarks that assuming the Bhargava conjecture for infinitely many $n$, the [parity conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71609/the-parity-conjecture), and the equidistribution of root numbers of $L$-functions of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $50$% of elliptic curves have rank $0$ and $50$% of elliptic curves have rank $1$ (this is called the Rank Distribution Conjecture).

> Does anyone have a conjectural
>   strategy for proving the
>   equidistribution of root numbers?

Silverberg mentions the Poonen-Rains conjecture together with the parity conjecture implying the Rank Distribution Conjecture (which in turn implies equidistribution of root number), so it could be that trying to prove the Poonen-Rains conjecture offers a possible approach, but it seems to me that one in fact needs the equidistribution conjecture as a hypothesis in the latter statement of Silverberg...

Comment: This was the topic of Harald Helfgott's thesis. http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0305435
See his website for some later papers on the subject, where he proves equiparity in some families. I think a big obstruction is proving something like Chowla's conjecture that the parity of the number of prime divisors of a random integer is equidistributed.

Comment: Also, Poonen-Rains for just one p implies that the parity of the p-Selmer rank is equidistributed. By a theorem of the Dokchitser brothers, the parity of the p-Selmer rank is exactly the parity of the analytic rank, except sometimes when there is p-torsion, which happens with density 0, so equidistribution of the root numbers follows.